# convert coordinates from json into SVG

Tags: svg, meshlab

I have exported a json file from a 3D program called meshlab which looks something like this:

```
  "version" : "0.1.0",

  "comment" : "Generated by MeshLab JSON Exporter",

  "id"      : 1,
  "name"    : "mesh",

  "vertices" :
  [
    {
      "name"       : "position_buffer",
      "size"       : 3,
      "type"       : "float32",
      "normalized" : false,
      "values"     :
      [
        10.3699, 12.1765, -10.4026, 10.2183, 12.2671, -10.6368, 10.4694, 12.5508, -10.6256, 8.86401, 12.667, -11.1871, 8.92628, 12.4419, -11.0507, 8.78183, 12.459, -11.0468, 10.4707, 14.5984, -11.6066, 10.609, 14.3137, -11.4362, 10.4292, 14.2369, -11.5423, 8.21309, 12.9991, -11.2778,
        8.335, 12.6943, -11.1197, 7.90955, 12.6514, -10.9905, 8.12493, 13.419, -11.473, 7.60838, 13.2001, -11.2427, 8.67802, 13.055, -11.3789, 8.602, 12.7194, -11.1796, 10.2127, 12.4886, -10.8037, 10.3542, 14.5035, -11.6542, 10.1942, 14.4931, -11.7254, 10.2228, 14.7139, -11.7583,
        10.0646, 13.1853, -11.4635, 9.83183, 13.1732, -11.606, 9.92727, 13.5153, -11.724, 9.50445, 14.5415, -11.9295, 9.38199, 14.7579, -12.0099, 9.64501, 14.8129, -11.9789, 9.64232, 13.0623, -11.5911, 9.60978, 13.2303, -11.6906, 10.6325, 14.813, -11.5264, 10.7926, 15.183, -11.4228,
        10.9659,.......
```

I guess these are coordinates, however I'd to use these and create an svg file, how coud I do this? Or just converting a meshlab file to svg, is this possible?

Comment: If they are 2D coordinates, you could create an SVG with the appropriate viewBox and a "path" element with the values as the path's "d" property. Just insert an "M" before the first value. However, the data doesn't appear to be polyline data, unless you intended it to make a series of overlapping triangles.

Answer (score 0):

I used inkskape in the end to export the obj file to svg.